# No package jq available

Tags: linux, jq, yum

I am trying to install jq on my linux 7 machine using

```
sudo yum install -y jq
```

But I am getting this error.

```
$ sudo yum install -y jq
Password:
Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, kabi, langpacks, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
Loading support for kernel ABI
No package jq available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What is the possible solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The `jq` package is not present in the default RHEL 7 or CentOS 7 repositories.

It is available in the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository, maintained by the Fedora project. Following the instructions from [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#Quickstart):

**RHEL 7**

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-*-optional-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-*-extras-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-ha-for-rhel-*-server-rpms
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

**CentOS 7**

```
yum install epel-release
```

Once the EPEL repository is added, you should be able to `yum install jq`.

Comment: It gives same error with epel-release

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a tool like [arkade](https://github.com/alexellis/arkade) which does not depend on central repositories getting updated but, instead relies on the the github releases for the respective tools. The tools also get installed in your home directory at `$HOME/.arkade/bin`.

Typical usage would be

```bash
# get arkade
curl -sL https://get.arkade.dev | sh
# create arkade bin directroy
mkdir $HOME/.arkade/bin
# make executable 
chmod +x arkade
# move to ARKADE_HOME/bin
mv arkade $HOME/.arkade/bin/
# create ark symlink
ln -s $HOME/.arkade/bin/arkade $HOME/.arkade/bin/ark

#add to PATH
export PATH=$HOME/.arkade/bin:$PATH

# get jq
ark get jq

# use jq
jq -V
```